# JSON.net - Write into JSON / JObject using path string

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a little utility where we extract values from JSON using `JObject.SelectToken(path)`.  We need to determine the paths at run-time. Works perfectly.

What I now need to do is to write back into the JSON (JObject or other) using the same path string.  I've hunted and searched and I can't quite find if there is anything that does this quite as cleanly as SelectToken does for reading.

(I'm also stuck in 3.5 CF)

For example, something like:

```
... JObject read in already ...

var theJToken = theJObject.SelectToken("animals.cat[3].name");
theTJoken.SetValue("Bob"); // Of course this doesn't exist

... serialize it ...
```

Comment: As my first "minuses", can you share why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`JToken.SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) actually returns a `JToken` which can be modified using [`JToken.Replace`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm). You can use that to replace the node within your JSON object, mutating the original object.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{ 'cats': [
                { 'name': 'cat 1' },
                { 'name': 'cat 2' },
                { 'name': 'cat 3' } ] }");

// get the token
JToken secondCatName = o.SelectToken("cats[1].name");

// replace the name
secondCatName.Replace("meow");

// and the original object has changed
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
// { "cats": [ { "name": "cat 1" }, { "name": "meow" }, { "name": "cat 3" } ] }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to have done the trick.  I didn't see Replace() and might not have thought to use it because I didn't realize that the JToken would implicitly take a string or whatever I sent in. Always learning!