# How to convert indexed collection from FormCollection to JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project and I am facing a problem with binding collections from IFormCollection to a JSON array.

Currently I have a web application that passes data from an IFormCollection through to other Web API microservices.

So, my form collection might look something like this pseudocode:

```
People[0].Name="Jon Skeet"&People[1].Name="SLaks"
```

When it is posted to my MVC controller as an IFormCollection, it pretty much looks the same, where the keys are "People[0].Name", "People[1].Name" and the values are "Jon Skeet" and "SLaks".

This is problematic because when I eventually serialize to JSON, instead of getting this:

```
{ People: [ { Name: "Jon Skeet" }, { Name: "SLaks"} ] }
```

I get this instead:

```
{ "People[0].Name": "Jon Skeet", "People[1].Name": "SLaks" }
```

Which does not bind to `[FromBody]IEnumerable<Person> People` when I post from my MVC controller to my microservice's controller for obvious reasons.

So, my question is, how can I get my IFormCollection to serialize to JSON in such a way that indexed collections serialize properly to a JSON array? Is there some kind of custom converter or something else I need to implement in order to make it work?

Please note that my MVC controller must take an IFormCollection because it acts as a catch-all controller that routes to the proper microservice based on the Request URL.

Comment: You didn't post how you are serializing, but I'd assume it's something like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(People)`?

Comment: Yes, I’m using JsonConvert.SerializeObject on the IFormCollection.

Comment: It looks like you want to populate a `JToken` hierarchy with a set of paths and values.  There's nothing built in to Json.NET for that so you will need to parse the path yourself.  [how to set the value of a json path using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17455052) has a partial answer that doesn't handle arrays.  [Set JSON attribute by path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33828942) and [JSON.net - Write into JSON / JObject using path string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31929433) only work if the intermediate containers already exist.

Comment: Is the parameter type `IFormCollection` in your action method where the form is originally posted to?  If so, have you tried change this type to `IEnumerable<Person>`?

Comment: Yes, it’s an IFormCollection. I cannot change the type because the controller action is a catch-all that passes the request payload on to a microservice, so it handles many different data shapes.

Comment: Is it possible to change it to extract just the People data from the `IFormCollection` for sending to the microservice as the correct type?

Comment: Here’s the thing: the MVC controller action doesn’t know what kind of data it’s getting. It is effectively acting as a router for underlying UI microservices in a composite application. The only solution that I can think of that works is posting form data rather than JSON to the underlying microservices, but that won’t work in all cases.